# How to combine unicode characters for keyboard layout?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-layout

I am trying to create my own Guarani keyboard layout. I'm having some issues with the **g̃** letter. According to wikipedia, it uses two unicodes.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%CC%83

I can't seem to figure out how to put them together when I'm writing my keyboard layout. I tried various combinatios such as **U+0067 U+0303** or **U0067+U0303**.

I even tried this solution but it didn't seem to work, **g\u0303**.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9707656/how-to-combine-unicode-characters

This is an example of the layout I'm creating

```
key <AD06> {[          y, Y, U1EF9, U1EF8               ]}; // y Y ỹ Ỹ
key <AC05> {[          g, G, g\u0303, G\u303            ]}; // g G g̃ G̃
```

The **ỹ** is working well. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried it as `U0067U0303` or `U0067\U0303` ?

Comment: I tried U0067\U0303 but it didn't work. U0067U0303 gives me this symbol ŋ.

Comment: Haha that seems odd! I upvoted your answer & I hope someone can help :(

Comment: This might help: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/custom-xkb-layout-in-which-one-key-creates-two-unicode-code-points

Comment: I've tried that before. I couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Comment: No, still no solution.

Comment: It is not possible. Refer to this https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xkeyboard-config/xkeyboard-config/-/issues/357