# How to make a custom xkb layout with combine unicode symbols?

Tags: 20.04, keyboard-layout, unicode, xkb

I'm trying to do a custom layout for a language call Pilaga.
I need to make this symbol 'b̶' that I make from combining this unicode char U+0062 U+0336

Now I having trouble trying to add this symbol to a custom layout using xkb. In the key <AB05> I tried to concatenate the symbols using + but it didn't work.

I already look some questions like [How to combine Unicode characters for keyboard layout?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/824190/how-to-combine-unicode-characters-for-keyboard-layout) or [Custom xkb layout in which one key creates two unicode code points](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/43073/custom-xkb-layout-in-which-one-key-creates-two-unicode-code-points) but unfortunately I couldn't get neither of those work around

```
// Modified for a real Spanish keyboard by Jon Tombs.

default  partial alphanumeric_keys
xkb_symbols "basic" {

    include "latin(type4)"

    name[Group1]="Pilaga";

 key <AE01>    { [         1,     exclam,          bar,   exclamdown ]    };
    key <AE03>    { [         3, numbersign, periodcentered,   sterling ]    };
    key <AE04>    { [         4,     dollar,   asciitilde,       dollar ]    };
    key <AE06>    { [         6,  ampersand,      notsign,  fiveeighths ]    };
    key <AE11>    { [apostrophe,   question,    backslash, questiondown ]    };
    key <AE12>    { [questiondown, exclamdown, dead_cedilla, dead_ogonek]    };

    key <AD11>    { [dead_acute, dead_diaeresis, dead_diaeresis, dead_abovering ]    };
    key <AD12>    { [      plus,   asterisk,   asciitilde,  dead_macron ]    };

    key <AC10>    { [    ntilde,     Ntilde,   asciitilde, dead_doubleacute ] };
    key <AC11>    { [ braceleft, bracketleft, dead_circumflex, braceleft]    };
    key <TLDE>    { [       bar,     degree,      notsign,      notsign ]    };

    key <BKSL>    { [braceright, bracketright, dead_grave,   braceright ]    };

    key <AB01> {[z, Z, U0295 ]};
    key <AB02> {[x, X, U02BC ]};
    key <AB03> {[c, C, U010D ]};

    key <AB05> {[b, B, U0062+U0336 ]};

    key <AC07> {[j, J, U03BB]};


    include "level3(ralt_switch)"
};


// EXTRAS:
 
partial alphanumeric_keys
    xkb_symbols "sun_type6" {
    include "sun_vndr/es(sun_type6)"
};
```

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04, and I am willing to try other alternatives besides xkb

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XKB does not allow you to combine two code points into one single symbol.

You can include `U0336` by itself somewhere, and then type `b` followed by `[whatever key you chose]`.

Comment: Is there an alternative to xkb that allows us to do combine two code points?

Comment: @Mattii: For that you would probably need to create an input method to work with e.g. IBus.

Comment: I wonder if this cannot be solved with the Compose key, Gunnar?

Comment: @Quasímodo: Not as far as I know. But even if it's possible, it wouldn't result in fewer key presses.